# VBA for removing duplicates in a specific column in another tab

Tags: vba, excel

this is a simple issue with simple VBA but I have not been able to find the answer through multiple searches.

I want to be able to remove duplicates in a column A in Sheet 2 of my workbook by pressing a button assigned to the macro in Sheet 1.

This is the code I have assigned to the button in Sheet 1:

```
Sub RemoveDupes()
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10350").RemoveDuplicates
End Sub
```

This code seems to just try to remove duplicates in the column in which the button exists or whatever column in whatever sheet I have clicked on. How do I specify to remove duplicates in column A in Sheet 2?

Comment: Try `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10350").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo` if you don;t have an header in the first row

Comment: The addition of the code yields the same results unfortunately.

Comment: do you refer a "Sheet2" as the worksheet name ? or Sheet2 is the `CodeName` ?

Comment: Sheet2 is the worksheet name in which Column A, where I want to remove duplicates is located.

Comment: Are you sure that duplicates are not removed? Sometimes leading/trailing spaces make values look the same but they are not. Manually add some definite duplicates to the column and see if they are removed. The code Shai Rado posted is working correctly. Also make sure that the button references to the correct sub `RemoveDupes`.

Comment: My issue is that the "Remove Duplicates" box comes up when I run the macro, but it specifies the wrong column or sheet. It specifies whatever sheet  and column my cursor has clicked in.

Comment: If you run `RemoveDupes` there doesn't come any box at all. It just silently removes the duplicates. I still assume that your button references to the wrong macro. Please confirm the tests I wrote in my last comment!

Comment: Thank you all, I have followed your suggestions, but am still getting the same result. It may be that I am working on Excel for Mac (not my first choice!).