# Remove duplicates based on specific column name

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba/macro... I want to remove duplicates based on the specified column name "Container" he entire row should be removed based on "container" column duplicates. My code is below in which I am getting type mismatch error 13. Please help below is my code and excel screenshot.

My Code

```
Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim colh

Set whs = Worksheets("POL")
colh = Array("Container")

With whs

 Set rng = Range("A1").End(xlDown)
 rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(colh), Header:=xlYes
 End With
```

***Based on column name "Container" I want to remove all entire row duplicate:***

[image]

Comment: [This might help you, just change the values according to your preferences, let me know if this helps ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827106/vba-for-removing-duplicates-in-a-specific-column-in-another-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify column number instead of header name. Try below codes

```
Sub RemDup()
Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set whs = Worksheets("POL")

     With whs.Range("A1:H" & lRow)
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=7, Header:=xlYes
     End With
     
End Sub
```

> If you want to use column header then you need to search for column header then find the column number from column header.

**#Edit: Find column header dynamically with match function.**

```
Sub RemDup()
Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, colNumber As Long
Dim colH As String

colH = "Container"
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set whs = Worksheets("POL")
colNumber = Application.Match(colH, whs.Range("A1:H1"), 0)

     With whs.Range("A1:H" & lRow)
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=colNumber, Header:=xlYes
     End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: range can be different each time column varies hence, instead of columns := 7 I want to put the column name and remove the entire row here .range("A1:H") can carry each time ... so it should remove all data based on the column name

Comment: Perfect sir @Harun24HR this is working.... However, I am still bit confused with the code line
With whs.Range("A1:H" &:lRow)
in this code line, there is a range defined "A1 to H"! I am not understating this part of the code. I would appreciate if you could tell me what exactly is happening there sir

Comment: `whs.Range("A1:H" &:lRow)` is setting range to remove duplicates from. `lRow` is specifying last used row. Suppose you data till `A200` then `"A1:H" &:lRow` is setting `A1:H200` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Your code having 3 issues.

First, the mismatch error 13 because the "colh" you used containing a string - "Container". However, the columns expect numbers.

Second, the "rng" included column A only. "RemoveDuplicates" will happen only for A column.

Third, the "with whs" actually is meaningless. You need to use ".Range("A1").End(xlDown)" to specify the Range is referring to whs worksheet. Otherwise, it will only use active sheet.

Finally, I usually use "cells(1,1).end(xltoright).column" etc to find the last column or row.
You may refer to the below code.

```
Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim colh

Set whs = Worksheets("POL")

With whs
 Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row, .Cells(1.1).End(xlToRight).Column))

 Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=7, Header:=xlYes '7 means column G
 End With
```

Comment: no it is not working I get error on line "set rang = .range.........."  error code 1004 method 'Range' of 'Object'_Worksheet failed

Comment: Oh, I just checked that. The program is due to the "cells" that should be ".cells". I just updated the code